# Is there any open source tool to automate oracle POS Xstore Application?

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, browser-automation, tools, test-automation-framework

I am looking for a tool to automate Oracle XStore Application,

Suitable tool to automate Oracle Xstore POS system.

Application: oracle Xstore OS: windows

Answer (score 1):

For Windows apps, there is [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium) for automating, it can easily be integrated into your current automation framework.